# Android drive pdf viewer is not able to open downloaded pdf files

Tags: android, jsp, pdf, pdf-generation

I have an web based application in which the end user has an option to download a pdf file. The application works fine when I am accessing it using my chrome browser on my laptop/desktop system and I am able to download/view the pdf file from the application. However, when I am trying to download the pdf file by accessing the same application from a chrome browser on an Android phone, the file gets downloaded but, when I try to view the contents of the file. It simply says that the file is of invalid format.

My web based application is JSP based application and is hosted on tomcat 6.0

Size of the file on windows system - 6 KB
Size of the file on Android phone - 1 KB

Android OS version - 4.4.4 (kitkat)
PDF software on Android - Drive PDF viewer

If the open the pdf file that I downloaded on the android phone on my windows system, it does not open. I then opened the android pdf file on my windows system in a notepad and I can see the following error

Exception: D:\sumeet\project\cars\comp\htmlclient\pdf\54f890fd0000000082aad2d3233f00021425576194.pdf (The system cannot find the file specified).

Can anyone of you please help me to understand what is the issue and how it can be resolved? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Ok, I found the solution, it was just that I had set the incorrect response MIME headers. Please refer this link http://www.digiblog.de/2011/04/android-and-the-download-file-headers/

Comment: response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="filename.pdf"");